# How to extract particular element from the column for each row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame in Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.8.

```
+----------+-------------------------------+
|item      |        other_items            |
+----------+-------------------------------+
|  111     |[[444,1.0],[333,0.5],[666,0.4]]|
|  222     |[[444,1.0],[333,0.5]]          |
|  333     |[]                             |
|  444     |[[111,2.0],[555,0.5],[777,0.2]]|
```

I want to get the following DataFrame:

```
+----------+-------------+
|item      | other_items |
+----------+-------------+
|  111     | 444         |
|  222     | 444         |
|  444     | 111         |
```

So, basically, I need to extract the first `item` from `other_items` for each row. Also, I need to ignore those rows that have empty array `[]` in `other_products`.

How can I do it?

I tried this approach, but it does not give me an expected result.

```
result = df.withColumn("other_items",$"other_items"(0))
```

The `printScheme` gives the following output:

```
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- other_items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("111", Seq(("111", 1.0), ("333", 0.5), ("666", 0.4))), ("333", Seq())
).toDF("item", "other_items")


df.select($"item", $"other_items"(0)("_1").alias("other_items"))
  .na.drop(Seq("other_items")).show
```

Where first `apply` (`$"other_items"(0)`) selects the first element of the array, the second `apply` (`_("_1")`) `selects` `_1` field, and `na.drop` removes `nulls` introduced by empty array.

```
+----+-----------+
|item|other_items|
+----+-----------+
| 111|        111|
+----+-----------+
```